# Can't execute .run file in Ubuntu container

Tags: linux, docker, gitlab-ci, microchip, xc8

there.

I'm trying to install the Microchip XC8 compiler on a Ubuntu container to make a pipeline for building the project with Gitlab CI. But there's no response after I run the "xc8-v1.45-full-install-linux-installer.run" file.

Here is the environment I have:

1. Official Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image on a Docker container
2. Docker version 19.03.13
3. Windows 10 as Docker host
4. Microchip XC8 v1.45 compiler

And the commands I used for downloading and installing are as following:

```sh
# Download XC8 from the Microchip official site
wget http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/xc8-v1.45-full-install-linux-installer.run

# Change the access permission
chmod +x xc8-v1.45-full-install-linux-installer.run

# Execute the ".run" file
./xc8-v1.45-full-install-linux-installer.run
```

After I did them all, there's no response. Obviously, something went wrong.

I have tried the installation process above on a native Ubuntu computer, and it just works fine.
Is there any prerequisite I missed? Or there have some ways for me to achieve the same purpose?
Thanks!

Comment: It makes sense to put anything which needs installing in the Dockerfile, the user who uses the container shouldn't be root, nor should it be a sudoer. you missing the point of docker is not a VM

Comment: thanks for the instruction!
I'll try to make Docker files and run the installer again

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem on 64 bit Ubuntu 20.04 as well.

I had several problems, could not change execution bit because it was on an NTFS partition and the executable required 32 bit libraries to run.

First I had to move the file from an NTFS partition so that I could set the file to executable. In my case I moved it to my downloads directory and then in that folder executed:

```
sudo chmod +x ./xc8-v1.42-full-install-linux-installer.run
```

It still would not run, so I checked its type by executing:

```
file ./xc8-v1.42-full-install-linux-installer.run
```

which resulted in the response:

```
./xc8-v1.42-full-install-linux-installer.run: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), statically linked, no section header
```

Eventually the main solutions was to install 32 bit libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

Finally I could install install that 32 bit library. Then running this worked:

```
sudo ./xc8-v1.42-full-install-linux-installer.run
```

Comment: wow, I thought no one can lend me a hand.
Since I have a new host now, maybe I can try it another day.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using existing MPLAB Docker repo

This GitLab.com project exists:
[MPLAB X IDE/IPE podman/docker container](https://gitlab.com/andersdra/docker-mplabx)

This may not help with your `.run` file problem, but maybe switching to an existing docker container might make it easier for you.
[They also work with `.run` files](https://gitlab.com/search?search=.run&project_id=11862838&search_code=true&snippets=false&repository_ref=master&nav_source=navbar), so you may find your solution over there as well.

*Features:*

- Has a general-purpose installation of MPLAB X and the toolchain.
- X11 forwarding for working in the IDE is supported.
- Can use USB from inside the container.
- Requires some setup. See readme for installation instructions.
- MIT License

Need to test this still myself, but just wanted to share here, might just as well.

Posted in the microchip forums by the creator:
[Dockerfile for MPLAB X IDE/IPE and toolchains](https://www.microchip.com/forums/FindPost/1094938)